# Calculating loss in YOLOv3 for all three scales

Tags: conv-neural-network, object-detection, tensorflow-estimator, loss-function, yolo

I'm currently trying to implement [YOLOv3](https://pjreddie.com/media/files/papers/YOLOv3.pdf) in TensorFlow, using the [Estimator API](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/custom_estimators). However, I'm stuck at the loss function. YOLOv3 makes predictions at three scales and I can't figure out, how to calculate the loss for all of them. I've already looked at the paper and also tried to find the loss function in the [darknet source code](https://github.com/pjreddie/darknet) but can't figure it out. I've also looked at the code for the loss function of another implementation [YOLOv3 TensorFlow implementation](https://github.com/maiminh1996/YOLOv3-tensorflow/blob/master/loss_function.py) but this hasn't really helped me to understand the calculation of the loss either.

Can someone explain how exactly the loss for training is calculated while taking into account the predictions of all three scales?